# Want to Shorten this code

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have this Code

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value != null )
    dgr.Cells["dgColTillDateCalculate"].Value = 
      (DateTime)dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value ;
}
```

**EDITED** 
Where cell `TillDate` is of DataGridViewDateTimeCell 
I want to short this code of Condition within foreach Loop into one line is there any way to do this  like

```
dgr.Cells["dgColTillDateCalculate"].Value = 
  (DateTime)dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value == null 
  ? doNothing 
  : dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value;
```

What should i do at `doNothing` please suggest more efficient way ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the `if` into the foreach using linq which would simplify the line inside:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["TillDate"].Value != null))
        {
            dgr.Cells["dgColTillDateCalculate"].Value = (DateTime)dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in DataGridView1.Rows)
 {
    dgr.Cells["dgColTillDateCalculate"].Value = 
          (DateTime)dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value == null 
          ? (DateTime?)null 
          : dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value;   
 }
```

Comment: It's my suggestion not copy.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
dgr.Cells["dgColTillDateCalculate"].Value = 
dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value == null 
? (DateTime?)null
: dgr.Cells["TillDate"].Value;
```

But since you was assigning value to `dgr.Cells["dgColTillDateCalculate"].Value`, check if `null` value required for assigning or not.

Comment: It gives Exception WHen Value is null "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @Co.Aden This code work perfectly for your edited question also.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your original code is perfect, you shouldn't change it. Anyway, replace `doNothing` with `dgr.Cells["dgColTillDateCalculate"].Value`, so it will get back its original value.

Comment: It gives error when value is null beacuse it cant cast null to DateTime Value

Comment: Then use Nullable<DateTime>.